# How to create facebook mobile application navigation bar?

Tags: facebook, html, css, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

does anyone know how to make navigation bar like facebook navigation bar on web mobile application (using sencha touch)?? really wants to add that navigation bar on my application.. thanks a lot.. :)

here's the example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Checkout lungo.js.  It's not Sencha, but their kitchen sink shows exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this little library. It is a really EASY Framework implementation (javascript, CSS3, HTML5) about how to build this kind of applications with a pretty sidebar such Facebook one.

Download "jbackbone-mobile" from here,
https://github.com/mjromper/jbackbone-mobile

and see this demo from any browser (device or desktop)
http://lab.ochio.com.es/jbackbone/index.html

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery mobile, the panel thing they have is exactly that and it can be just used the same way.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with lungo.js is that their framework is slow on mobiles(my android tablet and my lg viper 4g lte under wifi and 3g) so they might have the thing and the look you are looking for, but go with jquery mobile developers and using their panels is  even better than Lungo.js and if you are a designer you can figure it out things from there.